# How to set the gap between data items in a chartjs chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using the doghnut chart from chartjs.

How do I reduce (or increase) the size of the gap between data items ?

The white gap between each data point as shown on the doghnut chart here :

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html

(Apologies I would post an image but I am just shy of enough points to be able to do this)

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should RTFM.

The solution is on the chartjs website here :

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html

This fixed it :

```
Chart.defaults.global.elements.arc.borderWidth = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the border width to your desired size

```
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: data,
    options: options,
    borderWidth: 5 /* change this */
});
```

Comment: Thanks madalinivascu but see my answer below.

Comment: @Amj the same think, but i suggest my approach, you are overriding the defaults globally, my code only sets the border width for that particular chart